# GitHub Page Using Outdated Source Code/Cannot View Branches

Tags: html, github-actions, github-pages

I have a GitHub page and face two problems.

1. Whenever I update a file and check it on GitHub pages, the page reflects my old code, even after I commit. Why is this happening, how can I make sure the GitHub repository file and the webpage are the same?
2. How do I get to a branch on GitHub pages from the URL at [username].github.io? I have to open the repository outside of GitHub pages to view it, but want to view it from github.io.

I updated the file and committed it. I expected to see the latest version of my .md file reflected on my GitHub page. I got the last committed version.
I typed in [username].github.io/[branch name]/[file name.extension] expecting to see the file, but I got a 404.

Comment: How do you deploy to GitHub pages?